# basic touch gesture not working, using hammer.js

Tags: javascript, mobile, hammer.js

Im just beginning to learn javascript so I can implement touch gestures, I am using the hammer.js library, but even a simple piece of code doesnt seem to work, does anyone know if Im missing something obvious?

I am including hammer.js correctly (have tested it by putting in the path in the browser)
And I have included this code in the head...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var element = document.getElementById('tapdiv');
    var hammertime = Hammer(element).on("tap", function(event) {
    alert('hello!');
    });
</script>
```

and my html...

```
<div id="tapdiv">
 <img src="files/tabdiv.jpg" />
</div>
```

EDIT: IM also receiving this error in the console for hammer.js ...

> TypeError: el is null [Break On This Error]
>
> if(!css_props || !el.style) {

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It appears that your javascript is attempting to access an object in the DOM that doesn't exist yet -- make sure you execute your javascript after the DOM is ready:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.addEventListener('load', function() { 
    var element = document.getElementById('tapdiv');
    var hammertime = Hammer(element).on("tap", function(event) {
        alert('hello!');
    })

}, false);
</script>
```